# can one be "さびしい" without being "かなしい"?

Tags: word-choice

- Can someone be "さびしい" without being "かなしい"?
- I assume that one can be "かなしい" without being "さびしい". If this is not true, please explain.
- I don't think I've heard "かなしい" so much in conversation. Are there alternative words?

thank you.

Comment: Is this question related specifically to Japanese? Would it be different to English "lonely" and "sad"?

Comment: Well... unless you are translating simple nouns such as automobile or chopstick, you can never do direct translations. You cannot even directly translate simple adjectives such as colours or temperature. So, no. "さびしい" is not "lonely". "かなしい" is not "sad".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on the situation/context so if you can provide that, it would make for a better answer.

But speaking from a general sense..

**さびしい** or **さみしい** is used to describe a sad feeling stemming from missing someone or something; like something is missing from you heart. As stated above, loneliness doesn't quite fit, although it may fit in certain situations.

Example:

My girlfriend went off to school and I won't see her for six months. → さみしい

**かなしい** is used to describe a truly sad feeling, perhaps more in the traditional sense. Sad in US English tends to describe both さみしい and かなしい so it's a little difficult but.

Example:

Many children are dying from civil war in Syria. → かなしい

There are other similar words such as 心細い, 切ない, etc. that also reflect a certain sadness.

Example:

I moved to Japan with my wife but I don't speak Japanese and can't interact with the community. My wife doesn't understand my feelings and I feel helpless. → 心細い

My friend's girlfriend broke up with him because he wouldn't accept her religion although they were deeply in love. → 切ない

This doesn't quite answer your question but perhaps you can elaborate on what you are trying to get an answer to.

Comment: I'm just investigating why my habit is to rarely say "かなしい" (even though "sadness" is a fundamental emotion). I'm comfortable with the meaning of "さびしい", so I try to use that as a reference point for understanding "かなしい". I don't know why, but my habit is to say, when I am sad, I randomly select "落ち込んでいる", "しょげている", or "がっがりしている". To express that someone else is "sad", I say "可哀相" because I think that sounds playful. Of course, I am just guessing that "可哀相" sounds playful. I am also almost purely guessing "かなしいそう" is not said that much in conversation. I don't remember hearing it.

Comment: Your giving me synonyms, usage cases, and extended definitions is exactly what I was hoping for. That is how I like to study. thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Certainly!
I tried to exaggerate the examples so I'm not sure they are the best but I'm glad it helped. I didn't even think about your examples but that's definitely another type of sadness.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. For example, consider the phrase 寂しい場所. A desolate place. Do you think it necessarily must be 悲しい場所 as well? I don't.

Comment: But the question is clearly about a person, not a place.

Comment: Now that we've accepted a place can be 寂しい but not 悲しい, what exactly makes it impossible to accept that a person can be?

I mean, when I'm lonely, I'm more productive. If I want to be productive, I'm not sad that I'm lonely. I'm happy. At least in English. Is Japanese different in that if you're 寂しい, you're *always* 悲しい?

Comment: And I wonder, can a 場所 literally be 寂しい, or does it imply there must be people feeling that way about it? If the latter, 寂しい場所 is just another way of expressing one's feelings (about some place).

Comment: @Kyle As an english speaker, when i hear 'lonely' there is an implication that you are alone but dont want to be. "when I'm lonely, I'm more productive" sounds strange unless you take it to mean "im so bored of being alone, that i get some more productive stuff done instead'", instead of what i think you mean of "when i am alone (with no distractions), i'm more productive." So i can definitely understand why the asker poses the question, if you only equate さびしい with 'lonely'

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

People can be 悲しい without 寂しい, and vice versa. In fact, we can even find people describing themselves or others that way.

## 寂しいが、悲しくない

> **あぁなんか悲しくないけど寂しいね**。ずっと一緒だったからいなくなっちゃうのかって思うとつらいや

[twitter - しばはらみゆ (m0s020)](https://twitter.com/m0s020/status/511876608638984192)

---

> ツイッターを閉じてしまいましたが、その先には高みを目指すキミがいることを望んでます。
>
> だから
>
> **寂しいけど悲しくない**

[ameblo blog - smile](http://ameblo.jp/hina-tae-kiri/entry-11956764421.html)

---

> しあわせな最期を見送ることができました。
>
> **寂しいけれど、不思議と悲しくないのは**、光の世界に帰ったあとも、その存在を感じ続けられているから。いろんなところで助けられているのを感じてしまうから。そして、その度に、ニンマリして、ありがとうと言ってしまう。

[blog - birth harmony](http://birth-harmony.com/blog/posts/133)

---

> その　あたたかな気持ちで
>
> 心が　満たされているから　なのか･･･
>
> 「**寂しいけど　悲しくない感じ**」がしています。
>
> 「それって　どう違うの？」と娘に尋ねられ
>
> うまく答えられず・・・

[blog - cocolog-nifty](http://tiisanahosinokai.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2010/12/post-ba41.html)

---

> 「**真咲と会えなくなるのは、寂しい。でも悲しくないよ**。真咲が幸せにならない方が、もっと、悲しい」

[いしいめぐみ, 愛細胞分裂, ISBN-13 9784835579481](https://books.google.de/books?id=RSlVV7_o8O0C&pg=PA188)

---

> 「君も僕もその“苦の海“に溺れ続けた。だけど君はもう旅立っんだね、もう苦痛を味わうことのない世界へ。**僕は悲しくないよ、ただ少し寂しいんだよ**、だから涙が出てしまうのかな……」

[川室恵也【かわむろけいや】, 大罪の蝶, ISBN-13 9784286033891](https://books.google.de/books?id=z-myABgSc30C&pg=PA52)

## 悲しいが、寂しくない

> 2週間ぶりに会えるのに…
>   2人の1周年記念日なのに…
>   会えるのは夜ご飯のたった数時間なんて…(p_q*)ｼｸｼｸ
>
> **悲しいけど、寂しくないのは**
>   想い合ってるってちゃんとわかるから。
>   せっかく会えるからとびきり笑顔で居よう。

[twitter - ゆーこ (uco514)](https://twitter.com/uco514/status/420487834219204608)

---

> えみさんのお見送り  一緒にいってくれてありがと。 **バイバイだけど、悲しいけど、 会いにいく！ 寂しくない！** 札幌でも頑張れ〜♥♥

[pinsta - rarara1829](http://pinsta.me/rarara1829)

---

> 先週だけど、『おみおくりの作法』2度目の鑑賞。最後にガツンときて沈黙、そしてその後じわりとくる暖かさ、**悲しいけど寂しくない**、そんなステキなラストシーンにココロ癒される。

[twitter - HikariGoino](https://twitter.com/HikarGoino/status/579287284320628736)

---

> **悲しいのは寂しいからじゃない**
>
> 悲しいのは悔しいからじゃない
>
> 悲しいのは頑張れない自分

[blog girlstalk - まきちむ](http://www.ca-girlstalk.jp/blogs/articles/981533)

---

> 今日、ブリュ丸の大好きだったキャンディが虹の橋に行っちゃった。
>
> **悲しいけど、向こうにはブリュ丸もクッキーくんもいるから寂しくないよ。**
>
> 今頃、みんなで走り回って楽しんでるよね。
>
> BonBon丸もキャンディにお別れが出来てよかったよ。
>
> また逢える日まで　バイバイ

[diary - bnyut.petit](http://bnyut.petit.cc/banana/2382968)